# Debug behave context in step file with PyCharm CE

Tags: pycharm, bdd, python-behave

I am trying to debug a behave step file using PyCharm CE.

Following the instruction on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39201930/debugging-python-behave-steps-with-pycharm) I managed to run my test.

This is an example of feature file:

```
Feature: testing behave and pandas

Scenario: run a simple test
    Given a pandas dataframe
    When we check the number of columns
    Then the number of columns is 2
```

and step file:

```
from behave import *
import pandas as pd


@given("a pandas dataframe")
def given_dataframe(context):
    context.df = pd.DataFrame(
        {"col1": [1, 2], "col2": [3, 4]}
    )


@when("we check the number of columns")
def when_check_dataframe(context):
    context.num_col = len(context.df.columns)


@then("the number of columns is 2")
def then_num_col(context):
    assert context.num_col == 2
```

This test works but if, for example, I put a breakpoint in the `when` step and check the content of `context` I don't obtain any value:

```
Feature: testing behave and pandas # tutorial.feature:1
  Scenario: run a simple test           # tutorial.feature:3
    Given a pandas dataframe            # steps/tutorial.py:5
    When we check the number of columns # steps/tutorial.py:12
>>> context
>>> context.df
>>> context.df.columns
>>>
```

It's like the debugger can't print out any variable

Does anyone have any idea?
Do I have to add something in the `behave.ini`?

Unfortunately I can't move to the Pro version.

**Update**

I managed to print out using a logger:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger()

logger.info(context)
```

but it's not really convenient...
If there is I would prefer another method.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39201930/debugging-python-behave-steps-with-pycharm?noredirect=1&lq=1 check out this link

Comment: @NishantTuli thanks but that is the post I mentioned at the beginning of my post, I am following those instructions but I have to pass through the logger in any case and I don't have the Pro version